# Getting error while running program in node js related to solana web3

Tags: node.js, solana, metaplex, anchor-solana

I am trying to starting code to name my solana token i was following but he was sucessful but i am not. I am using ubuntu and I am coding in vscode and running the program like ts-node main.ts. [How to name your solana token](https://youtu.be/DQbt0-riooo)
Here is my code

```
import * as mpl from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata"
import * as web3 from "@solana/web3.js"

export function loadWalletKey(keypairFile:string): web3.Keypair
{
    const fs = require("fs");
    const loaded = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(
        new Uint8Array(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(keypairFile).toString())),
    );
    return loaded;
}


async function main(){
console.log("starting");
const myKeypair = loadWalletKey("BnAkGcoFJ9J7h3ZK8k3ZxbYQfa5RfEKmhz6UfxdwLR5d.json");
console.log(myKeypair.publicKey);
const accounts = {
    metadata:web3.PublicKey,
    mint:web3.PublicKey,
    mintAuthority:web3.PublicKey,
    payer:web3.PublicKey,
    updateAuthority:web3.PublicKey,
}
//mpl.createCreateMetadataAccountInstruction(accounts,args);
}

main();
```

And here is the error i am getting.

```
/home/cube/typescripts/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:644
        keyMeta.isSigner ||= accountMeta.isSigner;
                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1608:43)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/cube/typescripts/main.ts:3:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
```

I am expecting it to work the same without errors and print the public key as of video as of 12:00 to 12:25 i think in video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure to update to at least Node version 16. The newer web3.js library uses the `||=` syntax which is unsupported for versions before 16.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Issue was exactly the same as you mentioned.